# Battle.net friend list

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

I haven't played sc2 in like 4 years, and now when I logged in the battle.net app I see that the friend list shows 1 offline friend only. But when I visit my profile page on the battle.net website, the "Friends" page shows much more people. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different types of friends.

The battle.net client displays battle.net friends.  These are people where you added their RealID (email address) or BattleTag (account name and 4 digit number) to your friends list.  You can see these friends across all games.

Before RealId, games each supported their own in-game friend lists.  These friends are Starcraft II friends only and will not show up on the battle.net client or when playing other games.  However, they will show up inside Starcraft II and on the Starcraft website.

So in your case, it sounds like you have one battle.net friend and a bunch of Starcraft friends.

Comment: I don't know if the older games still support adding new non-battle.net friends.  I think WoW does, but Diablo/Starcraft may not.  Heroes of the Storm and Hearthstone default to battletag friends.

Answer (score 0):

Battle.net client shows your friends in only one region (the one you picked while logging in), but the website shows all regions.

To change your region:

1. Click on battle.net logo
2. Click on the log out button

[image: logout button]

3. On the login screen, click on the earth logo, and pick the region you used to play in.

[image: Earth logo]

4. Log back in, and you should be able to see all your friends.

Comment: I don't think it's that. If I log in with other region I see 0 friends

Comment: One thing I noticed is that on the web site profile page the one friend that I can see in the app friend list has another white nick name with a # number in it above the normal name

Comment: Hmm, all your friends should have it. Weird.

Comment: I installed the game, reached "playable" state and in the game I see the entire friend list, everybody is "Offline" but only that one friend I was talking about shows "Offline for x days"